# How to use plt.savefig() without using plt.show() and the end of matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

For example, this code works fine and saves the plt only when the plt.show() is present at the end. or else it just runs without saving any output.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation
import numpy as np

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(2*np.pi*i / 50)*np.sin(x))
    #fig.canvas.draw() not needed see comment by @tacaswell
    plt.savefig(str(i)+".png")
    return line,

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(0, 2*np.pi)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 200)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.zeros_like(x))
plt.draw()

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=5, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

PS - I tried using `ani.save(writer="ffmpeg",dpi=200)` and it works fine, but later on as I am using ffmpeg commands to convert the image sequence to animation, it shows invalid PNG signature.

Also I am new in this field so my appoligies if i did not follow any proper method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can comment out `plt.savefig(str(i)+".png")` when you are saving using `ffpmeg` i.e. maybe `gif or mp4` with `ani.save` and note that `plt.show()` should not be a concern if you remove it, still `plt.savefig(str(i)+".png")` would work

Comment: Removing `plt.show()` doesn't save the png files, I have tried. And as for `ani.save `, it works fine but I need an image sequence for conversion to animation via ffmpeg at a later stage.